# Create calculated field based on other calculated fields

Tags: looker-studio

I have two sum fields, field A and field B. Now I want to add field C that shows B as a percentage of A, but based on the totals, not the average of all the rows.

E.g. with the following data set:

```
A  |  B 
---+----
10 |  3 
20 |  4 
30 |  8
```

In my table I'm displaying sums of A and B (60 and 15 respectively).

i want to display for C 25% (15/60), not 25.5% (avg of 3/10, 4/20 and 8/30)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by performing a division that explicitly aggregates each field by [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) and setting the type to *Number* (*Percent*):

```
SUM(B) / SUM(A)
```

Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/99d88307-3716-42f6-88cb-d8dd9b0dea4e) to demonstrate:

[image]